# Shorten Titles on my RSS feed

Tags: php, substr

Im trying to shorten the titles on the items in my RSS feed.. to 30 characters but It just repeats one title over and over ... heres what I have so far

```
    foreach($nodes as $node) {

    $rss_feed .= '<item><title>';

    if(isset($node->caption) && $node->caption != '') {
        $rss_feed_long .= htmlspecialchars($node->caption, ENT_QUOTES);
        $short_title .= substr($rss_feed_long,0,30);
        $rss_feed .= $short_title;
    } else {
        $rss_feed .= 'photo';
    }
```

Comment: Wordwrap may be useful to look at - http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

Answer (score 0):

too many dots :) .= concatenates strings, so with every loop you add the caption once to $rss_feed_long, then the shortened version of that to $short_title.

Just change `$rss_feed_long .=` and `$short_title .=` to `$rss_feed_long =` and `$short_title =`

Comment: That worked! This is my updateif(isset($node->caption) && $node->caption != '') {
            $rss_feed_long = htmlspecialchars($node->caption, ENT_QUOTES);
            $short_title = substr($rss_feed_long,0,strpos($rss_feed_long,' ',15)).' ... ';
            $rss_feed .= $short_title;
        } <code>
-- the problem is now... if the string is shorter that 15 it will only show the ellipses

Comment: That's because strpos starts at the 15th character and if your string is shorter, there is no space to find. Just wrap it in a condition
`if (strlen($rss_feed_long) > 15)`